# Materializecss div vertically centered

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using materializecss and i want my DIV to be vertically centered the clean and maybe materializecss way?

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12  infobox center">
            <div class="col s6">
                <div class="card grey darken-3">
                    <div class="card-content white-text">
                        <span class="card-title">BOX 1</span>
                        <p>BOX 1</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col s6">
                <div class="card grey darken-3">
                    <div class="card-content white-text">
                        <span class="card-title">BOX 2</span><br>
                        <p>BOX 2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what i want: [image]

Comment: So where's your problem? What did you try? What doesn't work as expected?

Comment: As you can read and see i want my <div> to be in the vertical middle.

Comment: All three questions from my comment are unanswered; let me rephrase: *I assume you've looked up how to do this, where did it fail?*

Comment: @Thom, did you try my approach. Like you I was pretty puzzled. The docs are pretty vague about it. They completely omit to mention about the height

Answer (score 11):

To make `valign-wrapper` work the container itself must have some height. Most just *collapse* to the content height. You can either set the height to some fixed value or you can use percentages. But if you use percentages you need to make sure that your containers container also have some height.

In this example I'm showing how to make something vertically aligned inside the `body`:

So if you set `html` and `body` to height 100%:

```
html, body, .my-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Notice how I set both `html` and `body` to 100% in addition to my own wrapper class.

Now I can add the `valign-wrapper` to my container and you'll see that it's content get's centered:

```
<body>
    <div class="my-wrapper valign-wrapper center-align">
        ... content to be vertically aligned ...
    </div>
</body>
```

The point is your container **must** have a height otherwise it doesn't work. You can set the height yourself or let the layout handle it like in this case.

**Updated**

*Horizontal centering using grid classes*.

You can use a combination of grid sizes and offset to put content in the center (or where you fancy it):

```
<body>
    <div class="my-wrapper valign-wrapper center-align">
        ... content to be vertically aligned ...
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2 l6 offset-l3>
               ... content centered 6 wide on large ...
               ... content centered 8 wide on medium ...
               ... content centered 12 wide on small ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Notice that `row` and `col` goes hand in hand.

I created this <kbd>[example on Fiddle for you](https://jsfiddle.net/mblarsen/e3rk755z/)</kbd>

(ps: there must be a flex-box version of doing this as well)

Comment: @Thom did you try this solution?

Comment: Still didn't find the solution. This doesnt work also

Comment: It works, now the problem is to horizontally align it.

Comment: Just add `center-align` class to the container

Comment: I've updated the answer with a way to center using `row`, `col` and a combination of `s m l` and `offset` classes.

Comment: What do you mean @Bibipkins 'switch'?

Comment: @Michael [switch](https://materializecss.com/switches.html) is one of materialize classes. Anyway now I see that It does not work with any component unless I set parent`s height. And I cannot set the height as I it should be determined by content.

Answer (score 2):

In order to verticaly align a div,section or a part of design using materialize you should add `height` to `.valign-wrapper` as you can see here: [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/helpers.html)

Demo: [demo](https://jsbin.com/ledeyixepu/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: No, it is incomplete. If you are using `.valign-wrapper` alone it will not have enough height. You need somehow to ensure that ancestors has enough height. This can be done in an number of ways. See one my answer.

Answer (score 1):

i did it by adding an innerdiv class to the row which contains your infobox and then apply the below css, check if it suits you:

```
<style>
    .innerDiv{
        width: inherit;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
</style>        

<div class="container">            
    <div class="row innerdiv">
        <div class="col s12  infobox center-align">
            <div class="col s6">
                <div class="card grey darken-3">
                    <div class="card-content white-text">
                        <span class="card-title">BOX 1</span>
                        <p>BOX 1</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col s6">
                <div class="card grey darken-3">
                    <div class="card-content white-text">
                        <span class="card-title">BOX 2</span><br>
                        <p>BOX 2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Materializecss gives you some small helpers http://materializecss.com/helpers.html

The first one ist for vertial align.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add an CSS property to the `infobox` Div, or the card div:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Or maybe just add `Padding-top`

This both is not materializecss, but I think materialize don't have a feature for vertical align at all.

**//EDIT**

I was wrong. There is a Materialize way, just add the class `valign-wrapper` to the main Div here.
For headings you can use `valign`.

[About align in Materialize](http://materializecss.com/helpers.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work. It still stands where it still is, top.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Valign-wrapper doenst work that way, as many people are saying.

Answer (score 0):

**Text Align**

These classes are for horizontally aligning content: **.left-align**, **.right-align** and **.center-align**.

**left-align:** This should be left aligned

**right-align:** This should be right aligned

**center-align:** This should be center aligned

`<div><h5 class="left-align">This should be left aligned</h5></div>
  <div><h5 class="right-align">This should be right aligned</h5></div>
  <div><h5 class="center-align">This should be center aligned</h5></div>`

Answer (score 0):

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets first look at how materializecss aligns the code vertically using flexbox properties (search 'valign-wrapper' in the css file included in materialize.min.css file to examine).

```
.valign-wrapper{
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-align:center;
    -webkit-align-items:center;
    -ms-flex-align:center;
    align-items:center
}
```

Thus the above two elements could easily be aligned vertically using only HTML and CSS (see example below).

The CSS code:

```
.my-container{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    height: 100vh;
}
.box-container>div{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

And the HTML Code :)

```
<div class="my-container">
    <div class="box-container">
        <div>Box A</div>
        <div>Box B</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Learn more abour flexbox here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox